# Is every subgroup the centralizer of some element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

We were learning about centralizers in my abstract algebra class, and I had a thought about centralizers. Is every subgroup of a group $G$ the centralizer of some element? And if not, how many of the subgroups are?

My intuition is that this is not true (would be too nice of a result), but I can't immediately think of a counterexample.

Comment: If $G$ is non-trivial, the trivial subgroup $\langle e \rangle \subset G$ is never the centralizer $C_G(g)$ of an element $g \in G$. Proof: If $g \ne e$, then $g$ itself is contained in $C_g(g)$, whereas if $g = e$, then $C_G(e) = G$.

Comment: A comment on your " I can't immediately think of a counterexample". I personally always look at the groups of order less than $9$, as well as $A_4, S_4, A_5$.